# facebook not scraping my open graph content

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Things were going perfectly when I was using a heroku server.  The facebook app was scraping my content and creating open graph objects, etc.  I am transitioning to a different secure server and have entered all the relevant details about the new server in the facebook developer app settings page.  The simple php script that I used before looks like it is working just fine (no errors), but I don't see any new content showing up in facebook's open graph or my personal activities like I did before.

I suspect there is something else I need to do when switching servers other than just update the app settings page.

For my app domain I set:
https://secure96.hostgator.com

(even though this is a shared site.)

Thanks so much for any insights.

Here is the test URL I am trying to get facebook to recognize:

https://secure96.hostgator.com/~projectx/AMR/repeater.php?fb:app_id=360058754075871&og:type=allmyrecipes:recipe&og:title=Five%20Alarm%20Chili&og:description=A%20crowd%20favorite%20during%20the%20ballgame.&allmyrecipes:rating=4&allmyrecipes:servings=8&allmyrecipes:genres=&allmyrecipes:recipeingredients=1%20lb.%20Italian%20sausage%7C1%20t.%20basil%7C3%20cubes%20beef%20boullion%7C28%20ounces%20canned%20diced%20tomatoes%20in%20juice%7C1%20t.%20cayenne%20pepper%7C3%20stalks%20celery%20(chopped)%7C45%20ounces%20chili%20beans%7C0.33%20cup%20chili%20powder%7C1%20green%20pepper%20chopped%7C3%20t.%20dried%20cumin%7C1%20T%20dried%20oregano%7C12%20ounces%20good%20dark%20beer%7C3%20%20green%20chili%20peppers%20(copped)%7C2%20t.%20ground%20black%20pepper%7C2%20t.%20hot%20pepper%20sauce%7C2%20lbs.%20lean%20ground%20chuck%7C1%20T%20minced%20garlic%7C1%20large%20onion%20(chopped)%7C1%20t.%20paprika%7C1%20t.%20paprika%7C1%20red%20pepper%20(chopped)%7C3%20pinches%20salt%7C4%20ounces%20tomato%20paste&allmyrecipes:procedure=1.)%20Brown%20ground%20chuck%20and%20sausage%20in%20a%20large%20pot%20over%20medium-high%20heat.2.)%20Drain%20off%20excess%20fat.3.)%20Add%20all%20remaining%20ingredients%20and%20bring%20to%20a%20boil.4.)%20reduce%20heat%20and%20simmer%20for%20about%20three%20hours.5.)%20Let%20cool%20for%20an%20hour%20and%20refrigerate%20over%20night.6.)%20The%20following%20day,%20warm%20to%20serving%20temperature%20and%20optionally%20serve%20with%20sour%20cream,%20shredded%20sharp%20cheese,%20and/or%20corn%20chips.&allmyrecipes:shareflag=1&allmyrecipes:postername=Bill%20Chapman&allmyrecipes:posterid=1942295&body=1.)%20Brown%20ground%20chuck%20and%20sausage